# Why this problem happen to my pgadmin4 on my linux mint

Tags: python-3.x, database, pgadmin-4, enoent

Hello to every dear friend, Is there anyone who can help me with this problem with `pgadmin4`.

[image]

At the end of these lines it says:

> Failed to launch pgAdmin4.
>
> Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT

Answer (score 0):

review your route to python on system and the symbolic link on /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same error, I've found that **removing** pgadmin4 then **reinstalling** clears up this specific error.

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/