# "The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted" Linux Mint

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin, linux-mint, pgadmin-4

I am facing problems when trying to run Pgadmin4. This would be the error presented, does anyone know how to solve it?
PS: I use Linux Mint 21.1 (Vera) and Python 3.10

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/gabriel/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS: JS ERROR;JS LOG
  - LANGUAGE: pt_BR:pt:en
  - USER: gabriel
  - XDG_SEAT: seat0
  - XDG_SESSION_TYPE: x11
  - SHLVL: 0
  - HOME: /home/gabriel
  - DESKTOP_SESSION: cinnamon
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE: /usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop
  - GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
  - XDG_SEAT_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
  - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
  - CINNAMON_VERSION: 5.6.8
  - GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID: 68603
  - MANDATORY_PATH: /usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.mandatory.path
  - QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME: qt5ct
  - LOGNAME: gabriel
  - XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
  - DEFAULTS_PATH: /usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.default.path
  - XDG_SESSION_ID: c2
  - GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING: 1
  - GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID: this-is-deprecated
  - PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
  - GDM_LANG: pt_BR
  - GTK3_MODULES: xapp-gtk3-module
  - SESSION_MANAGER: local/gabriel-sm:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1542,unix/gabriel-sm:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1542
  - XDG_SESSION_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
  - XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
  - DISPLAY: :0
  - LANG: pt_BR.UTF-8
  - XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: X-Cinnamon
  - XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: cinnamon
  - XAUTHORITY: /home/gabriel/.Xauthority
  - XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR: /var/lib/lightdm-data/gabriel
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
  - SHELL: /bin/bash
  - QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
  - GDMSESSION: cinnamon
  - GPG_AGENT_INFO: /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
  - GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT: stderr
  - XDG_VTNR: 7
  - PWD: /home/gabriel
  - XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg
  - XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/cinnamon:/usr/share/gnome:/home/gabriel/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
  - GDK_BACKEND: x11
  - NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 37479
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 763f37a8-2241-4df7-a5bf-25f0210b266e
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
--------------------------------------------------------

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.006 Sec
Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error:
Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT
```

So far I have seen on some forums to downgrade from Python `3.10` to `3.9`
But without success so far

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Python virtual environment of your pgAdmin installation is broken. These types of problems can occur when you modify a system's Python installations (for example, by performing a system upgrade or incorrectly installing a version of Python). If you know what you are doing, you can try to repair or recreate the virtual environment found in `/usr/pgadmin4/venv`. However, the best course of action is to reinstall pgAdmin, as recommended by duplicates of this question (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73469312/failed-to-launch-pgadmin4-error-error-spawn-usr-pgadmin4-venv-bin-python3-en), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593419/why-this-problem-happen-to-my-pgadmin4-on-my-linux-mint) and possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68998977/pgadmin-4-not-working-anymore-after-postgresql-upgrade-from-v12-to-v13)).